# Is there any inbuild validation for linkedin profile url in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have googled for the **linkedin profile URL validation** in jquery.

But they are told me to use **regex or custom function** to validate that linkedin profile URL.

Is there any possible way to use bulid-in function like email validation ?

Example URL : https://www.linkedin.com/in/name-x-xxxxxxx/

Comment: So what do you want to validate? What's the output you want from that URL?

Comment: I want to validate this url...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Javascript` function:

```
val = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/name-x-xxxxxxx/';

if( /(ftp|http|https):\/\/?(?:www\.)?linkedin.com/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(val) ) {
   alert( 'VALID Linkedin URL' );
}else{
   alert( 'IN-VALID Linkedin URL' );
}
```

Comment: Before post answers you could check whether it's working or not...
I think it's not working...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3PuaQ/
Please check this..
I have already having this regex...
I need to get any possible way to validate this url using like email : true..

Comment: Do you want to validate only LinkedIn URL's or any Email? Also when you say `email : true`, what do you actually mean. I mean do you want apply your validation in your `HTML` tag?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this..**

```js
linkedin_url = 'http://www.linkedin.com/dummyname';

if( /(ftp|http|https):\/\/?(?:www\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(linkedin_url) ) {
   alert( 'Linkedin url is valid' );
}else{
   alert( 'Linkedin url is incorrect' );
}
```